# CsvReader can not read Request.Body in Asp.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, csvhelper

CsvReader read stream from Request Body in Asp.net core MVC occured unhandled exception.

■Exception

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware:
> Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the
> request.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are
> disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.

```
[ActionName("SaveLog")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveLog([FromHeader] HeaderDTO headerDTO)
{

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        //ヘッダを出力しないように指定
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
    };

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Operationlog>().ToList();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being affected by a breaking change from ASP.NET Core 3.0.

[HTTP: Synchronous IO disabled in all servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#http-synchronous-io-disabled-in-all-servers)

> Starting with ASP.NET Core 3.0, synchronous server operations are
> disabled by default.
>
> **Change description**
>
> AllowSynchronousIO is an option in each server that
> enables or disables synchronous IO APIs like `HttpRequest.Body.Read`,
> `HttpResponse.Body.Write`, and `Stream.Flush`. These APIs have long been a
> source of thread starvation and app hangs. Starting in ASP.NET Core
> 3.0 Preview 3, these synchronous operations are disabled by default.
>
> Affected servers:
>
> - Kestrel
> - HttpSys
> - IIS in-process
> - TestServer
>
> Expect errors similar to:
>
> - Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set    AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
> - Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set    AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
> - Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call FlushAsync or set    AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.
>
> Each server has an AllowSynchronousIO option that controls this
> behavior and the default for all of them is now false.

The package [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) already addressed it ,Convert your controller method to async and just call the async equivalent of the method in CsvHelper:

```cs
[ActionName("SaveLog")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveLog([FromHeader] HeaderDTO headerDTO)
{

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        //ヘッダを出力しないように指定
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
    };

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecordsAsync<Operationlog>();
        await foreach (var item in records)
        {
            //iterate through your records
        }
    }

    return Ok();
}
```